# How to deal with questions answerable with a simple web search?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've seen a significant number of questions that could be answered with a simple *{insert your favorite search engine here}* search.

Basically, had the Asker simply typed their question into Google they would have gotten an answer within the first few search results.

How do we deal with that? Leave a comment? ("What have you searched for?") Give them a `LMGTFY.com` link? Do our own search, find the best resource and use that to form our own answer (and thus get some cheap-and-easy reputation in the process)?

I mean, this would seem to fit well within the "do your research" admonition given to new users.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: And of course you gotta see this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=lmgtfy

Comment: downvote and close as a dupe (because the answer from google was probably a SO thread)

Comment: @Gracchus Because he used the search terms in the title. I sometimes enter the title verbatim as a quick way to find a dupe.

Comment: I suggest you do something else with your time other than worrying about how to "deal with" this non-issue.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should downvote questions that are poorly researched.  Not even bothering to do a simple web search using the terms already in the question itself is about the best example of insufficient research.  The tooltip specifically says that you should downvote questions that are poorly researched.

You can comment if you want, but you should make a point of trying to be polite and constructive when doing so.  Posting a [LMGTFY link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/lmgtfy/info) is banned specifically because it is a rude and unconstructive means of telling someone that they didn't do specific research.  Asking them what research they did, what they found, and what problems they had solving their problems after reading it is one approach; if people did research and didn't explain it in the question, then they can simply edit that it, if not, then it is a politer way of helping them realize that doing research is expected of them.

Comment: True enough, but if the question is clear and specific it will be useful to people other than the OP.

Comment: @emodendroket If the question can be solved by throwing that same question into google then *no, it won't*.  Either people searching for the answer to said question will find that other canonical source in future searches instead of your question, or you're only ever pulling traffic away from some other source that would have solved their problem.  There is never a problem solved that wouldn't have been otherwise, so nobody is really being helped.

Comment: Well, frankly, there are very few (almost no) questions on SO that couldn't have eventually been worked out by the OP if they knew the right place to look or the right way to search.

Comment: @emodendroket There are *plenty* of situations in which the author couldn't solve it with a simple web search.  There are plenty of questions that are inherently ill suited to web searches; they could use terms overloaded to mean other things, don't have specific terms defining what's going on at all, the author could not know what the term is for the relevant topic, they could be using the wrong term, some topic areas just aren't well documented and don't have a lot of quality web articles out there, etc.

Comment: The idea of what searches are "simple" is inherently subjective and probably has a lot to do with the asker's level of experience.

Comment: @emodendroket Yes, it is subjective.  You as a reader will need to use your judgement when deciding whether the problem is one that could be solved with the author's level of expertise.  This is not an objective fact about the question, it is a subjective judgement call.  When taking the question itself and throwing it, word for word, into google results in an answer you would feel comfortable posting as an answer to that question, then that judgement call is easy.  When you can't find the answer yourself it's also easy.  There's a lot of room in the middle for judgement.

Comment: I was being facetious about the LMGTFY link. I know that's rude.

Comment: @user3524344 Well, enough people actually do try to do it that it's worth being explicit in an answer.

Comment: My biggest pet peeve on SO is people expecting other people to do research before asking a question on SO.  It is so obvious that SO is more efficient than doing research, and people who object to SO being useful should STFU and just spend the rest of their lives reading assembly code.

Comment: @JonCrowell For some people, perhaps it is.  **This is a major problem that should be fixed**.  The site *shouldn't* be preferable to doing even cursory research for a problem.  If it is, then the site can't scale, and will fail to accomplish its purpose.

Comment: @Servy the fact that SO is scaling just fine completely undermines your point.

Comment: @JonCrowell The fact that SO *isn't* scaling just fine completely supports my point.

Comment: @Servy if you don't find that SO suits you, then I suggest that you take some of the burden off the site by using other forums.

Comment: @JonCrowell SO *does* suit me specifically because it is the one site in which there *is* a standard, where questions like these *aren't* welcome, and I *do* have tools to get rid of them.  If you just want to be able to have a human google searcher for you because typing your question into google is to hard for you then I suggest *you* use another site that *doesn't* have a problem with that.

Comment: @Servy why would I use another site when SO works fine for me and I have no problem with it?

Comment: @JonCrowell Ideally because the site would improve it's ability to close/delete inappropriate questions before they are able to be answered, forcing you to either provide *quality* contributions, which you seem unwilling to do, or to leave.  If that doesn't happen, then eventually the valuable contributors will be driven away from the site to one that *can* more effectively uphold a high standard of quality, and you'll move there because this site won't provide quality answers.

Comment: @JonCrowell "more efficient than doing research, … people who object to SO … should STFU"  The site is intended for professional and enthusiast programmers.  Those are the sort who typically *enjoy* learning about the technologies that they're using, and welcome an opportunity to do a bit of research about it.  Some questions are so good because they're the sort that a professional programmer, after spending a fair amount of time researching, is *still* stumped about! **That's** what we want: challenging, non-obvious, questions.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor That's what you want.  Speak for yourself, please.  What I want is answers to my questions, regardless of whether you think my questions are obvious or not.

Comment: @JonCrowell Those are the values the the site was founded under, and the goals that the site's current mission states as being what the goal of the site is.  What you want is very explicitly in conflict with the site's stated goals, so the question that you want to ask are not welcome here, regardless of whether or not you want them here.

Comment: @JonCrowell Fair enough;  *in my experience*, professional and enthusiast programmers like challenging problems with non-obvious, not readily Google-able answers that end up requiring some digging, and professional and enthusiast programmers find a satisfaction in answering those types of questions that they don't get with questions that have answers in the first Google hit for the query terms.  That's why we end up with (somewhat impolite) sites like LMGTFY;  some professional and enthusiast programmers didn't care for those types of questions.

Comment: @Servy I disagree.

Comment: @JonCrowell I stated cold hard facts, not an opinion that can be disagreed with, so that means that you're just flat wrong.

Comment: @Servy I disagree with your characterization.

Comment: @JonCrowell You can disagree that the world is round too if you want.  it doesn't make it any less incorrect.

Comment: @Servy You can claim that the world is flat if you want to, but it doesn't make it so.

Comment: @JonCrowell The site founders make the goals and mission of the site very clear.  These goals are well documented and readily available.  They conflict with your assertion of what the purpose of the site is.  My statement aren't true because I made the claim, they're true because they're supported by hard evidence.

Comment: @Servy I disagree.

Answer (score -6):

Stack Overflow is often among the first results when you search for these sorts of things. I don't know about you, but there are few things I find more infuriating than Googling something and coming to a page with some smart-aleck saying I should have just Googled my question.

I think you should just answer them (if you're so inclined) or leave them alone.  If there are duplicate questions obviously you can point to those.

Comment: Yes, there are topics that are not solved by simply throwing the question into Google, but there are also a *lot* that *are* solved by searching them.  Assuming that no topic will ever be solved through a web search is specifically contrary to the site guidelines that say that questions should be well researched.

Comment: I'm not really disputing that; what I'm saying is that a pile-on of people saying "Why didn't you Google it, LOL" ends up polluting future Google searches with unhelpful nonsense.

Comment: Which is why such questions shouldn't be answered, and should ideally just be deleted.  They're not useful to exist at all.

Answer (score -11):

I think you should put the simple search as answer, I mean give the terms of the search, could be a good tip , not results of the search , I meant please search for "term1 term2 [term3]...", may be a good help , when we know that a simple web search give you the results, the person which asked the question may don't know what terms should give you the answer .
Especially when the terms are not in the nature language of the person.

Comment: assuming that you are ok with that kind of questions, adding a simple search result is not a good answer. You can do it, but you have to say why you think those results contain relevant information. trivial answers are worse than trivial questions.

Comment: I see both sides...  If a similar question already exists on SO then I think closing as a dupe would be the way to go.  Maybe add a helpful comment with what terms could be used in a web or SO search to get the answer.  If not a dupe, why not post an answer on SO to help people that might use SO search along with links to the web resources used, and possibly the search terms that would have given the answer on the web.  I believe searching is a skill...

Answer (score -12):

Why do you have to "deal with" such questions?  You don't even have to read them if you don't want to.  If you'd like to engage, just answer the question.  If you don't want to answer the question or aren't interested, go watch some TV or do something else instead.

Comment: These questions drive away experts, consume time that could be better spend on *quality* and *useful* questions, they encourage the behavior thus creating a negative feedback loop, they generate a ton of noise which drowns out the useful signal of the site, inhibit the ability of people to develop the *necessary* skills of research and problem solving that are *required* to be in this field, etc.

Comment: @Servy I disagree.

Comment: Then use *any other programming Q/A site in existence* other than SO.  It was specifically designed to be a site that would have a high standard of quality, expect questions to be well formed and researched.  It is virtually unique in that regard.  It is in fact the *reason* for its success.  By removing those distinguishing features and turning it into yet another programming forum it would completely kill the site, for all of the reasons that this site's competition have failed to be succesful.

Comment: @Servy well I guess you'll have to give up on SO if you can't take it.

Comment: Or we can just downvote/close/delete these questions instead of destroying the entire site.  Personally I prefer that option.  If, in the event that people like you succeed in destroying this site's values and turn it into yet another worthless Q/A site then yes, I guess I'll have to leave.  Hopefully it doesn't come to that.

Comment: @Servy I don't know where you get this notion that SO is being destroyed.  To the contrary it is an excellent resource that works wonderfully.

Comment: A site turning from a useful resource to an un-useful one isn't something that happens overnight.  There is a huge amount of inertia behind the site; it takes a long time to fall, and fortunately there are plenty of things that (I hope) can still be done to prevent its devolution.  Currently we're just seeing warning signs of problems down the road, and smaller problems that are still things we can cope with.  The problem is that the low quality contributions, are increasing, and low quality contributors, such as yourself, aren't being ejected from the site effectively.

Comment: As low quality posts increase over time, it the overall post quality starts to go down.  Currently it hasn't gotten to the point that many of the site's experts have actually left, but if the problems *aren't* dealt with, eventually they will leave in great enough numbers for the site to lose its critical mass.  At that point answer quality will begin to devolve greatly, and the site will cease to become useful beyond being a record of already existing content.

Comment: @JonCrowell I somewhat agree with both you and @Servy even though I downvoted you. Its up to your discretion. If the question is not in a closeable category then answering it or leaving it alone are both fine options. I understand your frustration but this site's stated goal is to create  a library of answers to every programming question not directly to help individuals. So often people post out of desperation and are quite suprised that a Q/A site doesn't give them an A. But the reality is if their question must serve the site's goals their `desperation` is irrelevant.

Comment: @nsfyn55 I disagree that the site's goal is not to directly help individuals.  Often times people post simple questions out of frustration and then someone answers the simple question and everyone is happy.  Later, when someone else has the same simple question and they google it, the SO post with the supposedly stupid question will be the top result and everyone is happy again.  Questions that aren't good questions or don't have good answers fall off the top search results, so no big deal there, either.

Comment: I agree.  The example you provide isnt a closeable question.  It's probably a good question.  If a question already exists or isn't answerable it should be curated to reduce noise and keep the quality of the library intact.  Also note I said directly.  In most cases succinct questions both yield answers for the OP and serve the goals of the site