# What flag to use for trivial question, if any

Tags: discussion, flags, questions, close-reasons

Is there a flag agreed to be used for trivial question, or those question are still considered good question on SO?

If they are to be flagged I'm not sure about "Low quality" because is the inherent quality of the question that is low not the grammar or the content, at least not always, and there are no other specific flag (maybe Too trivial should be a flag in itself? No sure about it)

The latest example is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910917/how-to-get-rows-with-count-of-occurence-frequency-in-the-table) question: it's well written and with no grammar problem but it simply ask how to get the two most frequent value with SQL.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a "trivial" question. It's just that a lot of the really bad questions are *also* trivial. But don't confuse the vast array of reasons why they are bad with mere triviality.

Comment: If you feel a question shows no research effort, then *downvote*. It's not off-topic *just* because it is trivial to answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I consider trivial what can be solved with a little research (I already downvote them)

Comment: That's what the downvote is for. That doesn't make the question off-topic. If it is a dupe, close it as such. If answering requires writing a book, it's too broad. Etc. But trivial, by itself, is *not off-topic*.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251513/how-to-deal-with-questions-answerable-with-a-simple-web-search

Comment: Trivial often goes hand in hand with low research effort. It would be interesting to see some exceptions.

Comment: I'm not claiming community consensus on this, but for me personally, I don't have any particular objections to "trivial" questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550213). Sure, they could've done the research on Google and figured it out for themselves. I probably would have. But then again, our mission is to build a database of expert answers to programming problems. If I do all the research for myself but don't share it with anyone, I arguably subvert that purpose. The questions I *really* want to keep out are the code dumps—SO is not a debugging service, trivial or not.

Comment: Trivial questions are just fine, the most common problem with them on SO though are that they are very likely duplicates, since over the years, all trivial questions have been asked already.