# Close reason "Can be trivially googled" needed

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, trivial

I sometimes see questions to which an answer can be trivially found by googling. A glaring example is [this question about queues in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33409466/3150802). When I tried to vote to close the question I found that none of the reasons seemed to fit well. Other close votes deemed it "unclear" but actually, it seems to be a clear question which has a clear answer (use std::queue, look a cppreference.com for member names). I would think that it would do SO good to get rid of such questions ASAP in order to free valuable disk space, and that "it's trivially googleable" is a valid but distinct close reason which isn't really covered yet.

Relation to other close reasons: "Can be trivially googled" is related to a "No effort" close reason which has been [discussed elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/3150802). "No effort" would be a superset: It covers assignments and other questions which cannot be googled easily. A (re-?)introduction of a "No effort" close reason, which I support, would be an alternative.

Comment: Seems like a downvote offense, not a close vote offense. unless its a dupe of course.

Comment: If a question is decently formulated, asks a clear question with a clear solution to it and is not a duplicate, I don't think you should close vote it. You may downvote it because it may be low quality, but thats that.

Comment: If we don't allow questions that are easily answered by Google, how could we be the first result when people do Google?

Comment: @Anders Eh? If you can find a question/answer on SO through google you shouldn't be asking the question in any case as you'd be creating a dupe ;)

Comment: Downvote, mark as dupe. Very basic questions usually have a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: Oh..."disk space"...how quaint! :)

Comment: SO never hard deletes questions btw. So even if they are closed and deleted they will still be on the disks. Also diskspace lol

Comment: Refusing to do a poster's homework research and supplying a unique copypasta answer immediately, and without question, is punishable by sentences ranging rom getting slammed as 'mean and hostile', through 'two-a-day' serial downvoting,  to actual threats.

Comment: @Gimby Of course you should not ask dupes. But people should ask new questions, that can become the number one google result.

Comment: See also: [How to deal with questions answerable with a simple web search?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251513/3524344)

Comment: Related: [Should trivial re-occurring questions really be answered?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296157/3524344)

Comment: FAQ: [Embrace the non-Googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/262755)

Comment: FAQ: [How should we deal with Google questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8724/262755)

Comment: Related: [Should I ask a question that is easily Google-able?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191653/262755)

Comment: Related: [Is it reasonable to downvote a question that 'could be googled' but isn't a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262427/3524344)

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Thanks for the pointers -- some are different but your own question as well as the FAQ is an exact duplicate. Additionally, Hans Passant's answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/3150802) provides some bg. I guess I'll delete my question in order to save valuable disk space. (Maybe I should have googled my own question because indeed a fitting meta discussion is the first hit. I relied on SOM's suggestions instead which didn't come up with a good match, unless I missed something. I seriously thought I'm the first one to ever think or at least post about it.)

Comment: @PeterSchneider: SO only does hard-deletion in really exceptional circumstances, so no. And if there's no good duplicate on MSO, then *now* there is. Otherwise, dupe-close it.

Comment: Oh, I cannot delete a question which has answers. My effort to reduce waste produced more instead -- best regards from the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: See also: [Introduce a "general reference" close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86043)

Answer (score 6):

If this is implemented, can I go and close 90% of each darn question here at Stack Overflow?
Well, obviously not.

People have a question, they ask. There are many questions where OPs have tried searching before to get an answer, even if it was clear in the documentation. *Can be trivially googled* is not a good reason to close, because one, it's not off-topic. If you think a question is low quality, we have a mechanism to show that: down votes.

Even if this was implemented, what would count as "trivially googled"? This reason would be subject to the same abuse that the *Too Localized* reason once got. Dealing with Canadian English? That's too localized! Well, that's wrong: that's abuse of the reason and it got abolished because of that. This is essentially just a repeat.

---

### Simple answer: No. Downvote if you find a question that's low quality.

Comment: **1.** That a feature can be abused is in itself not a good reason to not implement it, since probably no feature is immune to abuse. You would need to demonstrate that it is *extraordinarily prone to abuse,* or that the abuse cases outweigh the use cases. **2.** I don't think 90% of the questions on SO can be trivially googled. **(Trivially.)** **3.** I would not mind if the ones that can were closed.

Comment: @PeterSchneider You're missing the fact that this existed at one point, and it was heavily abused. We're not here to close "searchable" questions, because the questions themselves are also searchable. Your arguments don't have much weight to them.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a bad reason to close a question.  As [Zizouz212 points out in their answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309194/4320665), there are many obvious avenues for abuse.  This is even more subjective than "too broad" and I think would cause too many legitimate questions from being posted.

But the more important consideration is that we can already deal with these kinds of questions.  If I have a programming question that is truly "trivially google-able" where do you think the first few hits will lead to?  Many times they will lead to another Stack Overflow question which means that the question can be **closed as a duplicate**.  So the solution is to google it as a close voter and look for duplicate closure.

For most of the remaining non-duplicate instances, I think this question basically reduce to the [proposal for closing for lack of effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253889/provide-not-enough-effort-as-a-new-close-reason).  [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253890/4320665) there suggests just downvoting and ignoring the posts so they qualify for automatic deletion via the roomba:

> These questions should be ignored, abandoned, and eventually culled.

Comment: Auto deletion is only a bonus if you ask me, and easily meddled with since trivially googled questions can also be trivially googled by the incredibly eager rep-collectors who don't care about the quality of a question. I find the reasoning in this answer on a related question (gimme codez) far more convincing and also relevant here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308842/424903 .